# If $σ ≡ dm/dt$ is the rate at which a continuous mass flow hits a car (say basketballs), why is $σ$ given by $σ$ by $σ = σ (u − v)/u$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, momentum, continuum-mechanics

If $σ \equiv \dfrac{dm}{dt}$ is the rate at which basketballs leave the hand of someone throwing them at a car. Why is the rate at which the basketballs hit the car related to the given $σ$ by $σ = \dfrac{σ (u − v)}{u}$?

Comment: You need to define $u$ and $v$.

Comment: u=velocity of the balls and v=velocity of the moving car . the velocity of the car changes due to continuous collision.

Comment: Use $v_2'=\frac{m_2v_2+m_1(2v_1-v_2)}{m_1+m_2}$, where 2 referes to the car and 1 to the ball.

Comment: @Roger, although your comment applies to a momentum exchange analysis of the system being considered, it seems that the OP is requesting an explanation for the calculation of the relative mass flow associated with the car (part of the system).

Comment: Please [edit] the clarifying definitions of $u$ and $v$ into your question, rather than expecting the confused reader to trawl the comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At time $t=0$ imagine a line of basketballs,travelling at speed $u$, of length $u$.

[image]

After one second all of the basketballs would have moved a distance $u$ as shown above.

[image]

If the back of the car was not moving then in one second all of the line of basketballs of length $u$ would have hot the back of the car.

Now imagine the car moving at the speed of the basketballs ie $v=u$.

[image]

None of the basketballs hit the car.

The intermediate step is with the car travelling at speed $v (<u)$.
[image]

Now only basketball in a length $u-v$ hit the car.

So the fraction of the basketballs which hit the moving car compared with a stationary car is $\dfrac{u-v}{u}$ and the required result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Let us recast the problem in the more familiar continuum formulation of fluid dynamics. Let $\rho:=\dfrac{\dot{m}}{A \cdot u}$ denote the *density* of the *flow of balls* where $0<A$ is the surface area of the ball. We assume that both the car and balls are moving in the same direction so that a ball would have to travel with a speed $v < u$ greater than the speed of the car w.r.t. the ground in order to be able to hit the car.

Using a reference frame attached to the car, it is easy to see that the mass flow rate observed is then $\rho A (u - v) = \dfrac{\dot{m}}{u} (u - v)$. A more mathematically rigorous derivation can be obtained by starting from the [Reynold's transport theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem).